# WSO2 API Manager - CORS

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to call an API through WSO2 API Manager but getting CORS error (browser console):

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://localhost:8243/blk/mantem-instituicoes/' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.
```

Followed this [document](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/design-api/advanced-topics/enabling-cors-for-apis/#EnablingCORSPerAPI) from official docs but it doesn't work.

How do I configure CORS correctly in order to call APIs from my application?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found how to set allowed origins:

1. If you uncheck "Allow All Origins" you can set the list of allowed hosts.

It's confuse because input appears only when you uncheck this option. See below:

[image]